# Private String properties are nullable in decompiled .java class Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I have a private String property in a Kotlin class and decompile the class into Java code, this property won't have the `@NotNull` annotation. In contrast if I declare a "public" String property, it will have the annotation `@NotNull` in the decompiled code.

Here an .kt example:

```
   class Boo {

      private var  myString : String = ""
      var myOtherString : String = ""

   }
```

and the decompiled .java equivalent:

```
public final class Boo {
   private String myString = "";
   @NotNull
   private String myOtherString = "";

   @NotNull
   public final String getMyOtherString() {
      return this.myOtherString;
   }

   public final void setMyOtherString(@NotNull String var1) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(var1, "<set-?>");
      this.myOtherString = var1;
   }

}
```

Why is it that `@NotNull` is not needed for private String properties?

Comment: There's no reason to check it, because you know that no classes from outside are going to set it to a null value. On the other hand, if it's public, a mischievous object from outside your project could set it to null.

Comment: @user Do you expect the annotation to be absent on a `val`?

Comment: The annotation doesn't actually do anything by itself.  It only provides information to other code "looking at" the annotated element.  Since you can't see a private field from outside the type, what would be the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the other way around: what is the benefit of providing `@NotNull` on the public property (and not e.g. hiding all the information in `@Metadata`)? It doesn't have any meaning to the JVM runtime; the main benefit is as documentation for the *users* of the class and their tools, so they know `getMyOtherString` never returns null. But they can't access `myString` in the first place, so there's no point annotating it.

This doesn't quite answer why the *field* `myOtherString` is annotated and not just the getter and setter; I would guess that's because it can be exposed with `@JvmField`, so writing code which annotates it in some circumstances is necessary and it was slightly more convenient to not check whether the field is visible.